# How do you make sure he selects one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I want him to select one instead of all.

```
if(input == ["1", "2"]) {

}
```

I expect the output is '1 or 2' but the actual output is '1,2'.
He goes only further in the code if it is '1,2' as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the array contains a certain element

```js
var input = "2";

if ( ["1", "2"].includes(input) ) {
  console.log("Included");
}
```

---

Another option is using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). This method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```js
var input = "2";

if ( ["1", "2"].indexOf(input) !== -1 ) {
  console.log("Included");
}
```

Comment: I would recommend going with `.includes(...)`

Comment: Me too, I prefer the `includes()`. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `index.Of`, it returns -1 when this is absent, otherwise it returns the index of the position.

```
input = ["1", "2"];

if(input.indexOf(you_value) != -1){}
```